# "Dopo" e "poi" (in senso temporale): sono sempre interscambiabili?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, adverbs

Mi sento insicura sull'uso degli avverbi "dopo" e "poi" in senso temporale. Ad esempio, posso dire

> - *dopo* te lo spiego

oppure

> - *poi* te lo spiego,

ma non so se questi avverbi con senso temporale si possano interscambiare in qualsiasi frase o invece ci siano costrutti nei quali sia preferibile usare uno o l'altro. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se ci limitiamo all'uso come avverbio, in generale sì, anche se IMHO dipende anche un po' dell'ordine delle parole. Ci sono alcuni esempi in cui a me personalmente suona meglio uno dei due:

> Bene: **Te lo spiego dopo.**
>
> Meno bene: **Te lo spiego poi.** (anche se è certamente usato)

In certi casi "dopo" è l'unica possibilità:

> **Lo rividi dieci anni dopo**.  (non: <s>dieci anni poi</s>)

Ci sono anche alcune espressioni idiomatiche:

> **Prima o poi**   (non: prima o dopo, anche se non posso escludere che qualcuno lo dica)
>
> **A dopo**   (non: <s>a poi</s>)

Colloquialmente si usa anche, ad esempio, in una elencazione di fatti o cause:

> Il tempo era ostile, e **poi bisogna anche dire che l'avversario era più forte**  (non: <s>e dopo bisogna anche dire...</s>. Comunque il "poi" qui è solo un rafforzativo, si può omettere e il senso non cambia)

"Poi" si usa anche per indicare "dopotutto", "in fin dei conti":

> Sembra molto difficile, **ma non è poi tanto complicato**. (non: <s>ma non è dopo tanto complicato</s>)

Per finire, nel parlato è abbastanza comune (soprattutto al nord, direi) l'uso pleonastico delle due parole:

> Di quest'argomento ne parliamo **poi dopo**.

Comment: La frase "poi bisogna anche dire che l'avversario era più forte" è sbagliata grammaticamente. "poi" e "anche" hanno lo stesso significato (consecutiva), quindi si utilizza o una o l'altra, si possono utlizzare entrambe spezzando le due frasi, mettendo la virgola dopo poi.

Comment: La frase contiene un pleonasmo, che non significa che sia sbagliata. Ho anche scritto che il "poi" si può omettere.

Answer (score 2):

Sono avverbi che sono sinonimi solo quando il tempo è indefinito (come nei tuoi esempi). Quando il tempo è determinato "poi" non si può usare.

È corretto dire:

> dopo 10 minuti te lo spiego,

"poi" in questo caso non si potrebbe usare.

Comment: Non sono d'accordo. "Dopo" non si userebbe mai per intendere "in un altro momento nel tempo" si userebbe per intendere "più tardi", quindi il tempo è finito. Non si usa per una cosa che faremmo il giorno successivo o la prossima settimana. Poi invece è completamente indeterminato.

Comment: Dopo è sicuremente sempre indeterminato, dopo si può usare per intendere "più tardi".

Comment: Si ma non può essere usato nella stessa casistica di poi, poi ha un significato molto più ampio.

Comment: Attenzione: nell'esempio «dopo 10 minuti te lo spiego», “dopo” non è un avverbio, ma una proposizione e quindi esula di fatto dalla questione dell'OP. Poi, sì, è giusto segnalare che una differenza tra “dopo” e “poi” è che il primo può essere usato anche come preposizione mentre il secondo no (al massimo, in italiano d'epoca, si sarebbe potuto dire “poi che” come sinonimo di “dopo che”).

Comment: ...oops: prEposizione.